# How do I configure Vim to not indent the current line upon hitting return?

Tags: vim

I have the following text:

```
        ");
```

When I hit <kbd>return</kbd> in insert mode, Vim creates a new line (as expected), but also indents the line on which <kbd>return</kbd> was hit:

```
            ");
```

Vim only does this with some lines, presumably when it thinks the indentation is incorrect.

How do I configure Vim to not indent the current line when hitting <kbd>return</kbd>? I want Vim to not touch the line at all. My current settings are as follows:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
```

Comment: Some plugins set/reset the `smartindent` flag; check it with `verbose set si?`

Comment: @sehe seems so: "Last set from /.../php.vim", however that script turns it _off_: `nosmartindent`

Comment: Note that it may be related to 'paste' option that messes a few options, 'smartindent' being one of them.

Comment: This happens in JavaScript mode as well.

Comment: Can you tell me which FileType you are working on?

Comment: Why not map enter key in normal mode? For example, `:imap <Enter> <ESC>o`. It might satisfy what you wanted?

Comment: @SibiCoder that won't split the line in case the cursor is in the middle of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filetype plugins may set `'cinkeys'` or `'indentkeys'` so
that automatic indenting is triggered when certain keys are
pressed. To turn this off, while leaving `'indentexpr'` intact
so that you can still indent with `==`, you can add the
following autocommand to your `vimrc`:

```
" Allow filetype detection, plugins and indent files ...
filetype plugin indent on

" ... but keep certain preferred defaults.
augroup overrideftplugins
    au!
    au FileType * set cinkeys= indentkeys=
augroup END
```

Note that the autocommand needs to come after the line that turns on filetype detection etc. This is because they are triggered in the order that they were
registered, and we want the autocommands for the overrides to fire after the autocommands that are set up for the ftplugins and indent scripts.

Comment: Been in my `vimrc` for over a decade. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to reproduce your issue with an XML document where one tag was not aligned with the others. I tried disabling autoindent, cindent and smartindent, but what finally fixed it for me was clearing the [indentexpr](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'indentexpr').

```
:setlocal indentexpr=
```

Alternatively, you can remove <kbd>return</kbd> from the list of [indentkeys](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'indentkeys'), or clear them altogether.

```
:setlocal indentkeys=
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function which can satisfy your need.

```
    function! Enter()
         let pos=getpos('.') 
         let substr = strpart(getline(pos[1], pos[2])
         if strlen(substr)==0
             exe("normal! o")
             exe("normal x")
             startinsert
             return 1
         else
             exe("normal! li\<Enter>")
             startinsert
             return 0
         endif
     endfunction
```

When the current cursor is at the end, and you press enter, it will create a new line and move to first column. (As usual, any lines below will be moved down)
When the cursor is at the middle of the line, and you press Enter, it will split the line.

To use the function, you can map like

```
     :imap <Enter> :call Enter()<CR>
```

This works well for C comments, subroutines/functions.

Comment: If any edge case is left out, let me know. I will try to add them here.